# Oracle Client and Oracle Server on different Operating systems

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Can we use oracle client on Windows 7 to access the Oracle Server installed on a Unix machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can have any combination as long as both operating systems are supported by Oracle.

Comment: Yes, Oracle provides different installer for both client and server, but there would be any issue if I connect through client on windows to server on unix?
there will be any problem regarding character set?

Comment: You won't have more character set problems than if both were on the same OS.

Comment: Yes, Oracle provides different installer for both client and server, but there would be any issue if I connect through client on windows to server on unix? there will be any problem regarding character set?

Comment: Hi,

Can anyone help me in the regard, that if we install Oracle client on a 32 bit Windows operating system, and try to connect to a oracle server installed on 64 bit windows operating system?

Will it connect or not because i am not able to